# Why spring data jpa unnecessary @Repository?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've looked through various documents and questions about it, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

I don't know how an **interface** that extends JpaRepository can be registered as a bean, and why it doesn't need the @Repository annotation.

In Spring, an interface cannot register a bean with that type without an implementation.

So I tried experimenting like JpaRepository myself, but it didn't work.

```java
// JpaRepository
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface WackRepository {

}

// SimpleJpaRepository
@Repository
public class WackRepositoryImpl implements WackRepository {
    
}

public interface HelloRepository extends WackRepository {

}

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HelloController {

    private final HelloRepository helloRepository;

}
```

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.HelloController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.HelloRepository' that could not be found

HelloController, of course, has no implementation, so it is not registered as a bean and throws an exception.

Comment: It doesn't work because you aren't extending the `Repository` interface of Spring Data, which is the key for detecting those interfaces.

Comment: @paiwmsn I have same problem, how you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data detects extensions of the `Repository` Interface.

In Spring Boot the interfaces extending `Repository` are found automatically without Spring Boot or if the interfaces are not below the `SpringBootApplication` in the package hierarchy you have to configure the packages:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.repositories")
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances

Comment: The explanation is lacking. An interface cannot be registered as a bean without an implementation.

Comment: Spring Data JPA creates the implementation on startup.